# how to pass input to api from angular forms without formControlName?

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

I am passing some data from angular to django rest api, Which is as follows

first what django need in for api:

```
notice
    {
      description: something,
      classname : in which class notice is provided,
      students : from dropdown
    }
```

what I am passing from angular

```
description by formController
students by formcontroller
```

now my issue is that I am not taking classname as input because It doesn't make sense here

so is there any other way by which I directly pass classname to api as input without showing on UI

my angular code:

```
this.announceForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  students   : [selectedStudents, Validators.required],
  description: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

here is django's input fields

[image: here is image of django restframework input]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. The value of the form is just an object. You can either hard-code the value you want as part of the form group, or you could add it to the value you pass to your service.

Just because you add a value to a form group doesn't mean you have to present it to the user.

Example using a hard-coded value:

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  students: [
   '', [ Validators.required ]
  ],
  classname: [
    'some value'
  ],
  description: [
    '', [ Validators.required ]
  ],
});
```

Or add the value later:

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  students: [
   '', [ Validators.required ]
  ],
  description: [
    '', [ Validators.required ]
  ],
});

const data = {
  ...this.form.value,
  classname: 'whatever',
};

this.yourService.whatever(data);
```

I typically just hard-code the value into the formgroup so I can pass `form.value` to the service method.

Comment: it can work but the value is also dynamic like it is coming from api and i got solution that i have to pass id to it that hard coded value but this answer helped for my another doubts so thanks

Comment: The value you use can come from anywhere, it doesn't have to be hard-coded.

Comment: yeah i got that